# Show the name and capital where the name and the capital have the same number of characters

Tags: sql

Greece has capital Athens.
Each of the strings 'Greece', and 'Athens' has 6 characters.

My code:

```
     SELECT name, capital
     FROM world
     WHERE len(name) = len(capital)
```

This gives me the name of countries having the same length as their capitals but the website I am practicing SQL with does not approve it. What do you think?

Comment: What is your _version_ of SQL (e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL) ?

Comment: Please add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as the description of the SQL tag says you should. Syntax and functionality varies widely between them, and it's a waste of both your time and ours if someone writes an answer only to find out it won't work on the DBMS you're using.

Comment: So this "website I am using" seems to be sqlzoo. In the exercise it states "You can use the LENGTH function to find the number of characters in a string.
For Microsoft SQL Server the function LENGTH is LEN". Clear enough if you ask me.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran across the same issue that you are having if you are working on SQL Zoo. The issue is only when you have MS SQL selected. If you change it to MySQL or PostgreSQL via the gear icon at the top right of the page, then the code below will work. I was unable to get the "Correct answer" with MS SQL for that challenge.

```
SELECT name, capital FROM world WHERE LENGTH(name) = LENGTH(capital);
```

Answer (score 2):

```sql
select name, capital
from world
where len(name) = len(capital)
```

For Microsoft SQL Server the function LENGTH is LEN

Answer (score 0):

LEN is for SQL Server Database and for other databases Length will work. Try using below statement...it will work

select name,capital from world where length(name) = length(capital)

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to use:

`LENGTH(name) = LENGTH(capital)`

I do not think "len" works.

Comment: Better ask the OP to provide the necessary information instead of just "believing" anything that maybe has nothing to do with the real issue.